# Can we have our own app Authentication logic to access Non-google API in a gmail add-on?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

We are trying to create a Google Add on using appScript. The application requires us to connect with Non-google API's, which does not implement OAuth2 but instead has a middleware that returns accesstoken via response.

Is there a way to implement our own logic to deal with the authorization?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the API.  Generally, they provide you with examples.

Comment: Hi Cooper, I have gone through the documentation, but there is only a mention on the OAuth flow. I was wondering if there could be a way to deal with an application that does not support OAuth